# How to pass data to a JSON array in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, for-loop

i want to pass data from one JSON array to another. My first json array is below:

```
var data = [{"Commodity":"Apparel and clothing accessories; knitted or crocheted"},{"Commodity":"Fish and crustaceans, molluscs and other aquatic invertebrates"},{"Commodity":"Meat, fish or crustaceans, molluscs or other aquatic invertebrates; preparations thereof"},{"Commodity":"Natural, cultured pearls; precious, semi-precious stones; precious metals, metals clad with precious metal, and articles thereof; imitation jewellery; coin"},{"Commodity":"Sugars and sugar confectionery"}];
```

I want to pass each of the "Commodity" values to my second JSON array. I tried using a for loop:

```
var arr = [];
for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    arr = [{"title":"Select a commodity:","options":[{"label":data[j]['Commodity'],"value":{"input":{"text":data[j]['Commodity']}}}],"description":"","response_type":"option"}];
}
```

I need each of the "Commodity" values to be filled inside the "label" and "text" property. However on output, only the last "Commodity" - "Sugars and sugar confectionery" is being displayed in the arr.

Any idea would help. Thank you.

UPDATES:

[image]

This is how the output looks like but the "Select a commodity" should only be printed out once. This is a response type option from ibm watson assistant.

Comment: Those are arrays, not JSON arrays. JSON is a text format.

Comment: Instead of `arr = [{...}]` which overwrites the array each time, simply use `arr.push({...})`

Comment: @AntonMitsev i did

Comment: Since you got answers with code that does exactly what you're asking but apparently you're looking for something different, please add an example of desired output to your quesition.

Comment: @ChrisG I updated the output in the question.

Comment: Each of your array elements has a `title` though, so you seem to be using a wrong approach in general. Seems like you're looking for this: https://jsfiddle.net/4z619nvc/

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for your help. I did implement it and it worked. That was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :

```
let arr = {
title: "Select a commodity:",
response_type: "option",
description: "",
options:data.map(element => {
  return {
    label: element.Commodity,
    value: {text: element.Commodity}
  }
}) 
}
console.log(arr);
```

OUTPUT

```
{
response_type: "option"
title: "Select a commodity:"
description: ""
options: Array(5)
0: {label: "Apparel and clothing accessories; knitted or crocheted", value: {…}}
1: {label: "Fish and crustaceans, molluscs and other aquatic invertebrates", value: {…}}
2: {label: "Meat, fish or crustaceans, molluscs or other aquatic invertebrates; preparations thereof", value: {…}}
3: {label: "Natural, cultured pearls; precious, semi-precious …, and articles thereof; imitation jewellery; coin", value: {…}}
4: {label: "Sugars and sugar confectionery", value: {…}}
}
```

The problem is you're actually using the "=" operator, which is re-assigning the value to your array - arr.
Instead of `arr = [{...`
Try using:

```
var arr = [];
for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
  arr.push({"title":"Select a commodity:","options":[{"label":data[j]['Commodity'],"value":{"input":{"text":data[j]['Commodity']}}}],"description":"","response_type":"option"});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but is there a way to add the "Commodity" values only inside "label" and "text" ? The "title", "description" and "response_type" should remain unique.

Comment: @Rohan How can they "remain unique"? The array is empty before the for loop.

Comment: @Rohan 
I suppose this is what you're asking for ??

let arr = {
  title: "Select a commodity:",
  response_type: "option",
  description: "",
  options:data.map(element => {
    return {
      label: element.Commodity,
      value: {text: element.Commodity}
    }
 }) 
}
console.log(arr);